# Unable to use leveldown package using Electron

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, leveldown

When I try to build my applicaton using electron it crashes on leveldown library

```
Error: The module '/Users/macosx/Documents/Electron/node_modules/leveldown/build/Release/leveldown.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
```

I have tried

```
rm -rf node_modules/leveldown
npm install
```

---

```
npm rebuild leveldown--update-binary
```

---

```
npm uninstall leveldown
```

---

Also tried this

> I had the same problem and nothing mentioned here worked for me. Here is what >worked for me:
>
> Require all dependencies you need in the main.js file that is run by
> electron. (this seemed to be the first important part for me) Run npm
> i -D electron-rebuild to add the electron-rebuild package Remove the
> node-modules folder, as well as the packages-lock.json file. Run npm i
> to install all modules. Run ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild to
> rebuild everything It is very important to run
> ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild directly after npm i otherwise it
> did not work on my mac.

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with this for a couple days.  The trick is to use [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild) to build the native node module, and to include the option [`node.__dirname = true`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node__dirname) in your webpack config, as the leveldown [bindings.js](https://github.com/Level/leveldown/blob/master/binding.js#L1) depend on the __dirname global provided by Node.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response, but can you elaborate on this, did you only run electron-rebuild or manually added node.__dirname ?

Comment: This answer assumes that you're build routine is using webpack, and if so, you should have some files such as `webpack.base.config.js` which contain the parameters used by webpack for the build.  In these files, there will be a `node` section, and you need to set the value of `_dirname` to `true` in that nested object. Once you've done that, when you re-run electron-rebuild, it should have the correctly defined (ambient) `__dirname` variable which is required by the leveldown build process.

Comment: Thank you for the __dirname trick!!!!!  Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: OMG you saved my life, I have been searching the darkest corners of the web for hours to find the solution!